# define variable to hold non-current date in bash

Tags: bash

The following command issued from a terminal gets me yesterday's date:

```
date --date='1 day ago' +%Y/%m/%d
```

I'm trying to write a bash script where the number of days is a command line arg.  I'd like to be able to store the resulting date in another variable and use it later in my script.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    x=$(date --date "$1 days ago" +%Y/%m/%d)
```

Where `$1` is the first command line argument.  Make sure you use double-quotes instead of single quotes, other wise the argument isn't expaneded.